# Swift: Setting width and height within a UIButton class

Tags: ios, iphone, class, swift, uibutton

So I have a 60x60 button on my storyboard and set a class for it.

```
class CustomRedButton: UIButton {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.layer.cornerRadius         = 0.5 * self.bounds.size.width
        self.backgroundColor            = UIColor.redColor()
        self.titleLabel!.font           = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 25)
        self.titleLabel!.textAlignment  = .Center

    }
}
```

What I want to do is adjust the size of the button, and the font in it, based on the size of the screen.

Comment: Managed to fix most with this great tutorial on adaptive layouts but would still prefer to do it with code... http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/

Answer (score 0):

Use view.bounds.maxX and view.bounds.maxY within the ViewController when you initialize it.

this is what I'm doing, but it only changes the width, not the height or the font size.

```
    button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (view.bounds.maxX / 2) - 10, height: 50))
    button1.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX - button1.bounds.width / 2 - 5, y: view.bounds.maxY - 160)

    button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (view.bounds.maxX / 2) - 10, height: 50))
    button2.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX + button1.bounds.width / 2 + 5, y: view.bounds.maxY - 160)

    button3 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (view.bounds.maxX / 2) - 10, height: 50))
    button3.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX - button1.bounds.width / 2 - 5, y: view.bounds.maxY - 100)

    button4 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (view.bounds.maxX / 2) - 10, height: 50))
    button4.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX + button1.bounds.width / 2 + 5, y: view.bounds.maxY - 100)
```

To do it for the height set the height to (view.bounds.maxY / 16 (or whatever number its up to you)) - 10 (spacing between buttons times 2) and change the center point to reflect the changes in height

To do the same for font size use view.bounds.maxX and divide it by something like 40. You get the idea.